# JOLT add key to array of object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

For each array object, get the id and assign it as a key to the array object.
I am trying to use the JOLT processor in NIFI.
Any help would be much appreciated!

**Input**:

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "catalog": {
        "id": "0981",
        "Desc": "Chess toy"
      },
      "quantity": 10,
      "price": 10.5
    },
    {
      "catalog": {
        "id": "01234",
        "Desc": "Water bottle"
      },
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 5.4
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "0981": {
        "catalog": {
          "id": "0981",
          "Desc": "Chess toy"
        },
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 10.5
      },
      "01234": {
        "catalog": {
          "id": "01234",
          "Desc": "Water bottle"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "price": 5.4
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your output isn't true. You can't have `"0981"` key in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "list": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[#4].@1,id.&",
            "@1,quantity": "&3[#4].@1,id.quantity",
            "@1,price": "&3[#4].@1,id.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where keys come from the identifier `@1,id`, `&3` represents going tree three levels up to get the literal `list` and `[#4]` will bring them in array type manner.

The following will do it all dynamically

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "cat*": {
            "@": "&3[#4].@(1,id).&1"
          },
          "*": "&2[#3].@(1,catalog.id).&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: With this spec the quantity and price attributes are getting eliminated.
I need quantity and price attributes

Comment: @VrushabhThosar I think you're still trying on the previous edit just before the abrupt deletion. Now, they exist. Check by the current one again please.

Comment: Can we add the remaning attributes dynamically? 
For example if I have 10 more attributes after quantity and price, do I need to list all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // list
        "*": { // 0, 1
          "catalog": {
            "@": "&3.@(1,id).&1"
          },
          "*": "&2.@(1,catalog.id).&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```